# iTerm2 Background image and split panes

Tags: desktop-customization, iterm2

Is it possible to have a background image for the whole window and not every split pane itself? I can't find how to do it anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a year late but I had the same question and ended up here.

There is no way to set a single background for the whole window but if you untick `Use Lion-style Fullscreen Windows` in the `General` Preferences, then you can set your background semi-transparent and have your wallpaper act as a single background when `iTerm2` is in full screen.

In my case this achieved the result I was looking for in the first place and is an alternative to what you were asking for.

Here's what mine looks like now:

[image]

You could also set transparency to 100%.

Note: You may also want to tick `Auto-hide menu bar in non-Lion fullscreen` in the `Appearance` tab.

Comment: This is extremely clever and neat solution. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 14):

Since `iTerm` version 3.3.0 (in Beta as of June 2019) you have a setting for this:

In `Preferences > Appearance > Panes` un-tick `Separate background images per pane`

[image]

Comment: Currently, this is the quick and easy solution/answer to the question

Comment: Works, and iTerm2 too

Answer (score 2):

In Iterm2 go to Preferences:

```
Profiles > Window > Background Image
```

Comment: is there a way to set this through AppleScript?